# Net use in php exec response

Tags: php, windows, networking

I using net use command with user and password to  connect sharing folders between computers

Using exec php I running in windows that commands

```
net use \\1.1.1.1\folder /user:user password /persistent:Yes > NUL
```

My question is how do I know if the command performed successfully. If the network is ready to work, how do I get response from net use.

all I want to know if the shared folder is ready to copy files

I run the service with exec()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what output one would normally get from `net use`, although logging it to a file should work, then you can do any number of things to know if the shared folder is ready.

```
>> output.log 2>&1
```

The above is a redirection to a log file, so the final command would be:

```
net use \\1.1.1.1\folder /user:user password /persistent:Yes >> output.log 2>&1
```

From there you can parse the log file, grep, etc. and look for the information you need.

> **`>>`** *appends to a file or creates the file if it doesn't exist.*
>   **`>`** *overwrites the file if it exists or creates it if it doesn't exist*